# Can anyone help me in below scenario on DAC

Tags: c

I am writing a c program to send a digital voltage value in bits to DAC (SAM4E) in order to get an analog output. 
The program is below:

```
#include "asf.h"
#include "conf_board.h"
#include "conf_clock.h"
#include "dacc_example.h"

int main (void)
{

sysclk_init();
board_init();


/* Reset DACC registers */
dacc_reset(DACC_BASE);

/* Half word transfer mode */
dacc_set_transfer_mode(DACC_BASE, 0);


dacc_set_timing(DACC_BASE,0, 0x10);


/* Disable TAG and select output channel DACC_CHANNEL */
dacc_set_channel_selection(DACC_BASE, DACC_CHANNEL);

/* Enable output channel DACC_CHANNEL */
dacc_enable_channel(DACC_BASE, DACC_CHANNEL);

/* Set up analog current */
dacc_set_analog_control(DACC_BASE, DACC_ANALOG_CONTROL);


uint32_t dac_val = 0;

while (1)
  {

// set voltage to minimum

#define SET_DAC_VAL 0x000

//set voltage to midpoint


// set voltage to 2.7V


//set voltage to 3.2V

//write the conversion value
dacc_write_conversion_data(DACC_BASE, SET_DAC_VAL, DACC_CHANNEL);
}
}
```

In the above code, I have configured the DAC and in the while loop I am trying to send the digital values to be converted into data conversion register. I want to set the voltages to minimum, midpoint, 2.7V and 3.2V. The maximum voltage is 3.3v and DAC is of 12 bit resolution.

Can anyone help me to set the voltage ??
or 
May I know how we represent 2.7 V in 12 bit binary format??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone help me to set the voltage ??

Setting the voltage is going to depend on how you are interacting with the DAC. Assuming that you are using a microcontroller, then you need to refer to the datasheet. It will describe the registers in the DAC module and how they work. Most of the time there is a code example in there as well.

> May I know how we represent 2.7 V in 12 bit binary format??

Your DAC has a 12-bit resolution. This means that you have 12-bits to represent the voltage value that you want to output on the DAC. This means you can represent 2^12 - 1 increments. Assuming that the DAC has a reference voltage of 3.3V, then each increment is 3.3/(2^12 - 1) volts. So if we wanted 2.7V, it would be represented by the value 2.7/(3.3/(2^12 - 1)) = 3350.

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to calculate the midpoint?? Also, am i writing the code correctly?? Does "#define SET_DAC_VAL 0xD16" execute??

Comment: The midpoint is calculated by (3.2+2.7)/2 which equals 2.95. 2.95/(3.3/(2^12 - 1)) = 3661. `#define SET_DAC_VAL 0xD16` doesn't execute anything. `#define` is a preprocessor directive and in this case it defines that constant. That constant is found in your code and replaced with the value that you defined it as (`0xD16`). You should read more about that [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/constants/create_define.php) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(programming))